# android: ImageView not displaying a bitmap from URL

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using `GRAPH API` to get posts of a `facebook` page. For posts which contains picture, the response contains the picture `URL`.

```
Response= {id:"...", message:"...",picture:"jpg image url"}
```

I am trying to load the image from the above `URL` resulted from `GRAPH API`.

And using below code to load image from URL.
[How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

I see resulting bitmap is not null, but my imageview shows nothing(not even a default image I set in the XML).

Note: Image is a `jpg` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found Error myself:** Actually image is getting loaded with above code.I was using a textview and then a imageview in a linear layout. When the content exceeds the screen, image is not displayed(however textview is scrolling by default). So I used a scrollview and then I can see the image even content exceeds the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
Library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

with below code

```
 ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));

            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.null_avtar) //this is the image that will be displayed if download fails
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();

            imageLoader.displayImage(avtar_url, mImageView, options);
```

Comment: Did i ask something cannot be done w/o external libraries? What's wrong with my code?